# select box append option not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, append, prompt

I have select box with searchable when i add new element the value should be added to the select box and selected too.

**HTML**

```
    <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
  <select id="selectpa_color" name="attribute_terms" tabindex="-1" class="chosen-select" multiple="" style="width: 350px; display: none;">
    <option value="28">Red</option>
    <option value="29">Blue</option>
    <option value="31">Greens</option>
    <option value="34">light</option>
    <option value="41">light1</option>
    <option value="62">new color</option>
  </select>
  <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" title="" id="selectpa_color_chosen" style="">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">
      <li class="search-field">
        <input type="text" style="width:25px;" autocomplete="off" class="default" value="Select Some Options" tabindex="8">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
      <ul class="chosen-results">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select_all_attributes" id="select_all_slug-color" onclick="selectAll(select_box-color,true)">Select All</a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select_no" id="select_no_slug-color">Select None</a>-->
  <input type="button" class="prompt_button" value="Add new" id="pa_color|5">
</td>
```

**Jquery :**

```
jQuery(".prompt_button").click( function(e){    
       var taxonomy =  jQuery(this).attr('id').split("|");      
       jPrompt('Enter a name for the new attribute term::', '', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r) {
        if( r )
        {
            var formData = {category_name: r,category_parent:0,taxonomy:taxonomy[0],shop_id:taxonomy[1]}; 
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: baseurl+'ajax_functions/add_new_attribute_term/',
                data: formData,
                beforeSend: function(){
                },
                success: function(response){
                alert(taxonomy[0]);alert(response);
                 jQuery('select#selectpa_'+taxonomy[0]).append(response);

               }
           });
        }

    });
```

**HTML View :** [image]

If i append some other value to another id it will append, but no in the select box and the ul li too..

Comment: @nanda : Now its working :) The another issue facing now is  the value was set to the selected correctly..now the issue is the selected value not displayed in the "select some options" fields

Comment: Nice dude...what u are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of your selector, while being constructed wrongly. What you have will try to select `#selectpa_pa_color` instead of `#selectpa_color`.

Change

```
jQuery('select#selectpa_'+taxonomy[0]).append(response);
```

to

```
jQuery('select#select'+taxonomy[0]).append(response).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

On a side note, you don't have to specify tagName if you are using id you can just do `jQuery('#select'+taxonomy[0])` which is more efficient.

Comment: yes ..it's working but the value was set to the selected correctly..now the issue is the selected value not displayed in the "select some options" fields :(

Comment: @AaruKarthiga Are you using chosen plugin. If so after adding the option you need to refresh chosen.

Comment: @AaruKarthiga If you want added values to reflect you need to trigger chosen updated.. see my code updated.